# The source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncEnumerable<FundedLoanDto>'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asynchronous, .net-5

We recently moved our project from netcore3. to net5.0 and all unit tests started failing with same error
The source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncEnumerable<Migo.API.Dtos.FundedLoanDto>'. Only sources that implement 'IAsyncEnumerable' can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.

It works fine in production. Only unit tests are failing

My actual class code -

```
 public async Task<GridDto> GetFundedLoans(LoanFilterDto loanFilter)
        {
            var query = GetLoanCommonFilter(loanFilter);
            query = query.Where(loan => EF.Functions.Like(loan.Status, "FUNDED"));
            if (loanFilter.FromDate.HasValue)
                query = query.Where(loan => loan.Funded.HasValue && loan.Funded.Value.Date >= loanFilter.FromDate.Value.Date);

            if (loanFilter.ToDate.HasValue)
                query = query.Where(loan => loan.Funded.HasValue && loan.Funded.Value.Date <= loanFilter.ToDate.Value);

            Expression<Func<EncompassLoanStatus, dynamic>> orderByExpression = GetLoanOrderByExpression(loanFilter.SortColumn);

            if (loanFilter.SortOrder?.ToUpper() == "DESC")
                query = query.OrderByDescending(orderByExpression);
            else
                query = query.OrderBy(orderByExpression);

            int recordsCount = query.Count();
            var loans = loanFilter.PageSize > 0 ? query.Skip((loanFilter.PageNumber - 1) * loanFilter.PageSize).Take(loanFilter.PageSize) : query;
            var fundedLoans = await loans.Select(loan => new FundedLoanDto()
            {
                BorrowerName = $"{loan.FirstName} {loan.LastName}",
                FundedDate = loan.Funded,
                LoanId = loan.EncompassId,
                LoanProduct = loan.LoanProgramName,
                ReceivedDate = loan.Createddate,
                SalesRep = loan.Salesrep
            }).ToListAsync();
            return new GridDto()
            {
                Records = fundedLoans,
                RecordsCount = recordsCount
            };
        }

        private IQueryable<EncompassLoanStatus> GetLoanCommonFilter(LoanFilterDto loanFilter)
        {
            var query = _context.EncompassLoanStatus.AsQueryable();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(loanFilter.BorrowerFirstName) == false)
                query = query.Where(loan => EF.Functions.Like(loan.FirstName, $"%{loanFilter.BorrowerFirstName}%"));

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(loanFilter.BorrowerLastName) == false)
                query = query.Where(loan => EF.Functions.Like(loan.LastName, $"%{loanFilter.BorrowerLastName}%"));

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(loanFilter.LoanProduct) == false)
                query = query.Where(loan => EF.Functions.Like(loan.LoanProgramName, $"%{loanFilter.LoanProduct}%"));

            if (loanFilter.DealerPhoneNumbers?.Length > 0)
                query = query.Where(loan => loanFilter.DealerPhoneNumbers.Contains(loan.Dealerphone));

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(loanFilter.SalesRep) == false)
                query = query.Where(loan => EF.Functions.Like(loan.Salesrep, $"%{loanFilter.SalesRep}%"));

            return query;
        }

        private Expression<Func<EncompassLoanStatus, dynamic>> GetLoanOrderByExpression(string orderByColumn)
        {
            Expression<Func<EncompassLoanStatus, dynamic>> orderByExpression;
            switch (orderByColumn?.ToUpper())
            {
                case "BORROWERNAME": orderByExpression = loan => loan.FirstName; break;
                case "LOANPRODUCT": orderByExpression = loan => loan.LoanProgramName; break;
                case "SALESREP": orderByExpression = loan => loan.Salesrep; break;
                case "CANCELLEDDATE": orderByExpression = loan => loan.Cancelled; break;
                case "FUNDEDDATE": orderByExpression = loan => loan.Funded; break;

                default: orderByExpression = loan => loan.Createddate; break;
            }
            return orderByExpression;
        }
```

My unit test is

```
 [Theory]
        [InlineData("BORROWERNAME")]
        public async Task GetFundedLoansSortsCorrectly(string sortColumn)
        {
            var mockEncompassLoanStatusSet = GetMockEncompassLoanStatusSet(FundedEncompassLoanStatuses);
            
            _mockDigitalApplicationContext.Setup(x => x.EncompassLoanStatus).Returns(mockEncompassLoanStatusSet.Object);


            var loanFilter = new LoanFilterDto
            {
                SortColumn = sortColumn,
                PageSize = 1,
                PageNumber = 1
            };

            var cancelledLoans = await _digitalApplicationRepository.GetFundedLoans(loanFilter);
            var records = ((List<FundedLoanDto>)cancelledLoans.Records).ToArray();

            Assert.Equal(3, cancelledLoans.RecordsCount);
            Assert.Equal("asdh", records[0].LoanId);
            Assert.Equal("asdg", records[1].LoanId);
            Assert.Equal("asdf", records[2].LoanId);
        }

private static Mock<DbSet<EncompassLoanStatus>> GetMockEncompassLoanStatusSet(List<EncompassLoanStatus> loanStatuses)
        {
            var mockEncompassLoanStatuses = loanStatuses.AsQueryable();

            var mockEncompassLoanStatusSet = new Mock<DbSet<EncompassLoanStatus>>();

            mockEncompassLoanStatusSet.As<IAsyncEnumerable<EncompassLoanStatus>>()
                .Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                .Returns(new TestAsyncEnumerator<EncompassLoanStatus>(mockEncompassLoanStatuses.GetEnumerator()));

            mockEncompassLoanStatusSet.As<IQueryable<EncompassLoanStatus>>()
                .Setup(m => m.Provider)
                .Returns(new TestAsyncQueryProvider<EncompassLoanStatus>(mockEncompassLoanStatuses.Provider));

            mockEncompassLoanStatusSet.As<IQueryable<EncompassLoanStatus>>().Setup(m => m.Expression)
                .Returns(mockEncompassLoanStatuses.Expression);
            mockEncompassLoanStatusSet.As<IQueryable<EncompassLoanStatus>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType)
                .Returns(mockEncompassLoanStatuses.ElementType);
            mockEncompassLoanStatusSet.As<IQueryable<EncompassLoanStatus>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator())
                .Returns(mockEncompassLoanStatuses.GetEnumerator());
            return mockEncompassLoanStatusSet;
        }
```

It is failing in class at line

```
            var fundedLoans = await loans.Select(loan => new FundedLoanDto()
            {
                BorrowerName = $"{loan.FirstName} {loan.LastName}",
                FundedDate = loan.Funded,
                LoanId = loan.EncompassId,
                LoanProduct = loan.LoanProgramName,
                ReceivedDate = loan.Createddate,
                SalesRep = loan.Salesrep
            }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting your bin/obj folders and reinstalling all your Nuget packages?

Comment: It is working fine in Development and Production. Only unit tests are failing

Comment: Is your unit test project also updated to .net 5?

Comment: Yes. I think there is an issue in mocking method GetMockEncompassLoanStatusSet

Comment: You cannot mock `async` operations against an IQueryable using a `List` behind the scenes. Look at MoqQueryable (https://www.nuget.org/packages/MockQueryable.Moq) to wrap your desired `List<T>` in a manner that both Synchronous and `async` operations will be happy with.

Comment: BuildMock works fine for all st.s except
`query = query.Where(loan => EF.Functions.Like(loan.Status, "FUNDED"));`

Error says The 'Like' method is not supported because the query has switched to client-evaluation. This usually happens when the arguments to the method cannot be translated to server. Rewrite the query to avoid client evaluation of arguments so that method can be translated to server.